# Is there a way to overload a function in Go?

Tags: go, overloading

I have read that there is no way to overload a function in Go. I mean by overloading, a way to have two functions with the same name but with different arguments.

I have seen something strange in the built-in functions of Go:

Let's suppose `ch1` is a channel variable:

```
ch1 := make(chan string)
```

It is possible to read somthing from a channel like this:

```
result := <-ch1
```

But it is also possible to get a status like this:

```
result, status := <-ch1
```

So, is there is a  way to overloaded a function like a built-in function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

For obvious reasons this is called the **comma ok** idiom (not a function overload ):

```
result, status := <-ch1
```

1- Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/bsjJ-P3C6f) for Channels:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan string, 1)
    ch1 <- `Hi`
    result, status := <-ch1
    fmt.Println(result, status) // Hi true

    ch1 <- `Hi`
    close(ch1)
    result, status = <-ch1
    fmt.Println(result, status) // Hi true

    result, status = <-ch1
    fmt.Println(result, status) //    false
}
```

output:

```
Hi true
Hi true
 false
```

---

2- Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/v05WBo3Qj9) for Maps:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]int{"One": 1, "Two": 2}

    result, status := m["One"]
    fmt.Println(result, status) // 1 true

    result, status = m["Two"]
    fmt.Println(result, status) // 2 true

    result, status = m["Zero"]
    fmt.Println(result, status) //  0  false
}
```

output:

```
1 true
2 true
0 false
```

---

3- Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/-pQFxezq91) for `interface` conversions and type assertions:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var s interface{} = `One`

    result, status := s.(string)
    fmt.Println(result, status) // One true

    i, status := s.(int)
    fmt.Println(i, status) // 0 false
}
```

output:

```
One true
0 false
```

Answer (score 4):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Built-in functions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Built-in_functions)
>
> Built-in functions are predeclared. They are called like any other
>   function but some of them accept a type instead of an expression as
>   the first argument.
>
> The built-in functions do not have standard Go types, so they can only
>   appear in call expressions; they cannot be used as function values.

---

The Go programming language does not allow function overloading except for Go built-in functions. There is no way for you to overload your functions.